# Dynamic linking is less secure?

Tags: security, dynamic-linking

I know the difference between static and dynamic linking, and this isn't another question asking for the difference (I have looked and read them). I didn't find any questions about the security of dynamic linking.

I have been reading the book, "Expert C Programming." It has a nice section on linking. If my understanding of it is correct, wouldn't a downside of dynamic linking be less security? If the program relies on the OS to provide a stable and proper library, then there is an opportunity for the libraries on the OS to be infected/malicious. There isn't much a program could do to prevent a tainted library.

Is this right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is true but to replace a DLL with a malicious one, an attacker would have to have write access to the file system. If they have that, then all bets are off - your security is compromised anyway.

Comment: That makes sense, too. I was just surprised not to see it come up in any of the texts or anything, but thanks for confirming it!